# How to rotate axis label and hide some of them?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I was trying to plot a time series and its differentiation.

However, I have two problems with the x axis label:

1. it's not rotating;
2. there is too many months and too little space in the canvas.

How can I rotate all labels and hide a few dates?

I can't show the data because of confidentiality. But it's basically a (numeric) column with the series and the (date) index.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize':(9,7), 'figure.dpi':120})

# Original Series
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True);
axes[0, 0].plot(df.teste); 
axes[0, 0].set_title('Original Series');
axes[0,0].set_xticklabels(df.index,rotation=90)
plot_acf(df.teste, ax=axes[0, 1]);

# 1st Differencing
axes[1, 0].plot(df.teste.diff()); 
axes[1, 0].set_title('1st Order Differencing');
plot_acf(df.teste.diff().dropna(), ax=axes[1, 1]);

# 2nd Differencing
axes[2, 0].plot(df.teste.diff().diff()); 
axes[2, 0].set_title('2nd Order Differencing');
axes[2,0].set_xticklabels(df.index,rotation=90)
plot_acf(df.teste.diff().diff().dropna(), ax=axes[2, 1]);
```

This is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (8, 4))

ax[0].plot(x, y, 'r-', lw = 2)
ax[0].set_xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 0.25))

ax[1].plot(x, y, 'r-', lw = 2)
ax[1].set_xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation = 90)

plt.show()
```

which gives me this plot as an example:

[image]

As you can see, both graph have the same options, but in the second one (on the right side) I set:

```
ax[1].set_xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
```

to space the `xticks` in order to remove some of them, and

```
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation = 90)
```

to rotate their orientations.

Comment: I still don't know how to apply it in my case. When I use axes[2, 0].set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(df2), 3)) I get what I want but just for the graph in the bottom right. The other one still has a messy label

Comment: Because in writing `axes[2, 0]` you are specifying that graph. Loop over all graph `[i, j]` and apply them the same method

Comment: Weird... I tried all combinations and none of them worked.